# Finding a conditional probability for draws from an urn

Tags: binomial-coefficients, conditional-probability

An urn contains 10 red, 6 blue, and 8 black marbles. What is the probability that 3 black marbles are simultaneously selected given that 1 blue marble was already selected?

I am obtaining two different answers based on my approach. I guess that approach 2 is closer to the correct answer, but I cannot see the flaw in the reasoning.

Approach 1: Since 1 blue marble was selected (and not replaced), there remain 23 marbles of which 8 are black, 10 are red, and 5 are blue. Therefore, the probability of now choosing 3 black marbles simultaneously is

$$\frac{{8 \choose 3}}{{23 \choose 3}}=0.0316.$$

Approach 2: Using the conditional probability formula $$P(A\mid B)=\frac{P(A\&B)}{P(B)},$$ we obtain

$$\frac{\frac{{6 \choose 1}{8 \choose 3}}{{24 \choose 4}}}{\frac{{6 \choose 1}}{{24 \choose 1}}}=0.126.$$

Comment: How do you define $A\&B$? If it is "draw $4$, check if first is blue, rest are black", then denominator for it should be $24 \choose 4$, not $23 \choose 3$.

Comment: I define $A\&B$ to be the event that we have 1 blue and 3 black. I agree and have replaced the 3 with a 4, but the decimal is still off.

Comment: It should be $24 \choose 4$, not $24 \choose 3$, because we choose from original $24$ balls.

Comment: And it also should be divided by $4$, because you calculated probability of "one blue, three black" instead of "first blue, rest black".

Comment: And $\binom{24}4\binom41$ counts ways to draw 4 from 24 balls and choose 1 among those to be the first. This equals $\binom{24}1\binom{23}3$, which counts ways to: draw 1 from 24 *then* 3 from the remaining 23.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct probability is the first one:  Given that the first marble drawn is blue and not replaced, the probability that the next three marbles drawn without replacement are all black is $\binom{8}{3}/\binom{23}{3} = \frac{8}{253}$.

Why is the second computation wrong?  The answer becomes clear if we examine the joint probability $\Pr[A \cap B]$ more closely.  You wrote $$\Pr[A \cap B] = \frac{\color{blue}{\binom{6}{1}}\binom{8}{3}\color{red}{\binom{10}{0}}}{\binom{24}{4}},$$ where I have added the factor $\binom{10}{0}$ to illustrate that this is a generalized hypergeometric probability we are calculating.  But this is not correct, because it ignores the sequential ordering of the outcomes implied by the observation of the events $A$ and $B$.  In particular, the event $A \cap B$ includes the following outcomes:
$$(blue, black, black, black) \\
(black, blue, black, black) \\
(black, black, blue, black) \\
(black, black, black, blue)$$
In other words, $A \cap B$ allows the outcome in which the first draw was black, then exactly two black and one blue marble is drawn from the second draw of three marbles, because the hypergeometric distribution models the drawing process as if all marbles are taken without respect to ordering.  This is disallowed under the original interpretation of the question.

You will also note that this difference is reinforced when we see that under the second computation, the conditional probability calculated is $4$ times the first calculation.

Comment: In short: $\mathsf P(A\cap B)=\left.\binom61\binom83\middle/\binom{24}1\binom{23}{3}\right.$ as it measures the probability for **obtaining 1 from 6 blue balls *followed by* 3 from 8 black balls, when selecting any 1 from all 24 balls *followed by* any 3 from 23 remaining balls**. The task of sorting the balls into *first ball*, and *next three balls*, must be accounted for in both numerator and denominator. So, of course, dividing this by $\mathsf P(B)=\left.\binom61\middle/\binom{24}1\right.$, gives the same result as approach 1. $\mathsf P(A\mid B)=\left.\binom83\middle/\binom{23}3\right.$.